# code generation for a compiler based on ANTLR

Tags: antlr, code-generation

I am working on a compiler for a language and I have got some problems with operator precedence.
The language is pretty simple, nothing complicated. It has functions, statements, expressions, etc. It's based on a youtube series of videos "Let#s build a compiler".

There is already code generated for the Java Platform (JVM) and everything is fine there.

However I wanted to be able to also generate code for the INTEL platform and so I decided to add a code generator for the 80x86.
I'm still at the very beginning, I have a functional toolchain. I can generate assembly code and then have the assembler (masm32) translate the code to object files and then the linker creates an exe file out of it.
So far so good - however I have problems in generating code for performing divisions and multiplications. In the grammar I first perform divisions and then perform multiplications.

The parser uses a visitor, to be exactly there is one for the JVM platform and one for the 80x86 platform (Windows).

The main problem appears to me that the parser creates a stack by calling the visit-methods and that is very well suited for the JVM platform, since it is also stack based.
However the 80x86 platform works with registers, so I have to load the operands into registers.

For example an expression like "8 * 4 / 2" should evaluate to 16 and the relevant assembly code should look like

```
mov eax, 8
mov ebx, 4
imul eax,ebx
mov ebx, 2
idiv ebx
```

However the code generated is

```
 mov eax, 8
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 2
 idiv ebx
 imul eax, ebx
```

Due to the stackbased approach there are two consecutive mov-statements for eax, which is of course completely wrong, since the first value for eax gets overwritten with the second one.

So my question is how to transform the stackbased approach in a more "linear" approach?

I hope that the wording of my question is comprehensible and not too complicated.

Thanks a lot for reading and answering!

Here is the relevant part of the grammar:

```
expression: 
            left=expression DIV   right=expression   #Div
          | left=expression MUL   right=expression   #Mul
          | left=expression MINUS right=expression   #Minus
          | left=expression PLUS  right=expression   #Plus
          | '(' expression ')'                       #Parens 
          | left=expression operator=(LT | LE | GT | GE | EQUAL | NOTEQUAL)    right=expression   #Relational
          | left=expression AND right=expression     #And
          | left=expression OR right=expression      #Or
          | number=NUMBER                            #Number   
          | text=STRING                              #String
          | varName=IDENTIFIER                       #Variable
          | functionCall                             #FuncCallExpression
      ;
```

Comment: The parser doesn't invoke the visitor. Visitors are run on the tree after the parser has finished. And yes, the way that visitors work is "stack based" in the sense that they invoke themselves recursively and thus use the call stack. This not some ANTLR peculiarity, but just how visitors work. In fact any way of traversing a tree will involve some kind of recursion or explicit stack. However, none of that means that you can't generate code for a non-stack based language from a visitor.

Comment: We can't really tell you why your attempt generates wrong code without knowing your code or how it decides which registers to use.

Comment: Regardless of that, you should also keep in mind that x86 assembly (just like any other assembly language for real world machine code) has a limited number of registers and you won't be able to store all intermediate values in registers. So for large expressions you'll have to store some intermediate values in memory regardless of which register allocation strategy you use. So as a first baby step, it would make sense if you just store everything in memory and don't bother with register allocation.

Comment: You defined the operators incorrectly. That's why your code gen isn't working. First, you need to verify that parsing works as expected, and it doesn't because you ordered the multiplicative operators due to the fact they are different alts of the `expression` rule. Model expressions after [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/74d7b892a1a16ed45801abbda8f3fa297a01e78f/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4#L41).

Comment: And, if I were you, I'd just generate to LLVM. It isn't a hard target to generate to (though you may have to do thunking calls to C++, the hardest part), and it'll generate real code that really works.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Of course I am aware that without code it's difficult to say what is wrong but I did not want you bother with tons of code....

@kaby76: Thanks a lot for your hint. I had already tried this approach with a much smaller grammar but it did not work as expected. 
When I tried this approach with my own grammer everything worked flawlessly - obviously I must have made a mistake when I tried the first time.
Thank you very much for pointing me again in this direction!

Comment: Thanks also for reminding me of LLVM - I will have a look at it, however I must admit, I am not too keen on having a lot of trouble with JNI;-)